# Kleene star semantics and set comparison

Tags: algorithm, math, set, regular-language, kleene-star

Say we have two languages L1 and L2, is the following condition below considered false?

```
(L1L2)* = L1*L2*
```

I'm assuming this because say:

Leftside of condition:

```
L1 = {a,b}
L2 = {c,d}

C = L1.L2
C = {ac,ad,bc,bd}

C* = {empty, 'acad','adbc','bdac',...}
```

Rightside of condition

```
L1 = {a,b}
L2 = {c,d}

L1* = {a,b,aa,ab,ba,bb,...}
L2* = {c,d,cc,cd,dc,dd,...}

C = L1*.L2*
```

C therefore can't have any element c within that has a combination such as "adbc" as can be demonstrated on the Leftside of the argument, therefore the original argument is false.

Is this approach valid?

Comment: Are L1 and L2 elements optional in C? You say that `c` is in `C`, for example, but that doesn't seem to follow from C being an element from L1 followed by an element of L2. I think `C = {ac, ad, bc, bd}` only.

Comment: Updated. Yeah that was an error.

Comment: Your `C*` still contains an error, where it can only consist of sequences of elements of `C`. `'cab'`, `'dab'` and `'a'` aren't part of that. Instead you'll have `C* = {empty, ac, ad, bc, bd, acac, acad, acbc, acbd, ...}`.

Comment: As @PaulHankin very clearly showed, to prove two languages aren't equal, give one string that's in one of the languages and not in the other. Then you're done. Pouring more words over the proof isn't necessary or good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't follow your proof, but if `L1={a}` and `L2={b}`, then `(L1L2)*` contains `abab`, and `L1*L2*` doesn't. So they're not equal.

Comment: yeah sorry there was an error during concatenation on the leftside of the argument which i fixed, but didn't fix the final argument. I updated the question, but yes essentially it follows the same idea. Thanks.